# Java Transform: Return NullPayload

Tags: mule, mule-component

I don't know what occurs. Java Transform return a NullPayload.

**XML CODE**:

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<flow name="teste-tranformationFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/trans" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <custom-transformer class="TransformTest" doc:name="Java"/>
    <logger message="SUPER TESTE #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

**JAVA CODE**:

```
public class TransformTest extends AbstractMessageTransformer {

  @Override
  public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding) throws TransformerException {

    String s = "";
    try {
        s = ((ParameterMap)message.getInboundProperty("http.query.params")).get("id").toString();   

        message.setOutboundProperty("id", s + "***");           

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return message;
  }

}
```

Logger print :

> SUPER TESTE null

Is Java Transform implementation correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing the payload `#[payload]`, not the "id" outbound property set in the transformer. `#[message.outboundProperties.propertyName]` --> `#[message.outboundProperties.id]`

If you want to set an outbound property, you don’t need a `Custom Java Transformer`, you can do it with a `Property Transformer`, take a look to the documentation:

> https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/property-transformer-reference

For the `Mule Message` structure understanding:

> https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-fundamentals/v/3.7/mule-message-structure

For doing transformations (Dataweave):

> https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/using-dataweave-in-studio

Comment: Ok, its works! But, another question: I does not understand why sometimes I can access data with #[message.payload.id] (like query JDBC results) and in  transformation I need to access with #[message.outboundProperties.id]. Thanks for advance!

Comment: Mule Message is composed basically by: 1) Header (inbound properties and outbound properties that contains meta data of the message, like headers, query params, cookies, etc) 2) Payload (contains your specific business data). The results of a JDBC query are part of the payload, is the data itself, not the metadata. Take a look to the updated post.

Comment: Nice! I have  several situation like this: DB1 (MySQL) -> Transform -> DB2 (Oracle). I need to transform data a lot. I think that Custom Java Transform is the better solution, because of the details in this case. But I still did not find how to return #[message.payload] instead #[message.outboundProperties]. I would like to return a payload.

Comment: If you decide to make the transformation in a Java Custom Transformer instead of current transformers like Dataweave, you have to set the payload in your java class:  message.setPayload("your payload. It could be a Map of values"); return message;